# How to force MS word to "cache" a large doc —while opening? (And not after beginning working on it)

Tags: microsoft-word, freeze, cache, microsoft-word-2013, cpu-cache

I am working with large documents which (probably) requires word to "cache" large amount of data. So it freezes, (high CPU, fan) during few minutes, after few minutes of editing. The freezing probably occur when word start to cache. It seems normal for large doc (the same docx does that to my colleague who has a much powerful computer, it just takes longer to freeze). It should theoretically cache when I open the doc, but it doesn’t. So this stop me during my work.

It freezes (and thus caches) only after a certain amount of edit. To force it to cache I need to edit it for several minutes, then it'll freeze, and I'll have to wait for its resurrection (which takes a while).

Is there a way to force word to cache the doc when I open it (and not after few edits on it) ?

(MS word 2013, hardware graphic acceleration option disabled). Other people get the same issue with next versions.

EDIT1: working as draft view as suggested by Máté Juhász dramatically speed the software. But even opening the doc as draft (using an macro, since the check box is useless), doesn't solve that caching issue.  The doc still need to warm up, for few minutes. But the interesting things is that is start warming up much quicker. So, it doesn't seem to be related to pagination (there is no page in draft).

Edit2: I tried to be sure to force it to repaginate with a macro, but that does not do anything. It doesn't seems to be a repagination issue.

Comment: I'm not sure it's caching. I'd suppose delay is due to auto save or re-pagination. You can avoid them by disabling auto save and editing in draft view respectively. Look the status bar (bottom) when break happens to see what's going on.

Comment: @MátéJuhász thanks for your advices! You are probably rights, it might not be caching, but repagination since working as a draft (instead of web view) did dramatically speed up the computer. But I still get that starting issue. Disabling the “background repagination” (In option/advance/general Enable background repagination) bugs: it doesn’t save this when I close and reopen the doc. Same problem when I check the “allow openeing doc in draft view”, theses check box doesn’t seems to do anything. (My friend confirmed it)

Comment: For those interested to work in draft, and to remove the dotted line of the auto pagination, follow this advice: http://word.tips.net/T000012_Getting_Rid_of_Automatic_Page-Break_Lines.html